# jQuery Validation Weirdness

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.2, and I am trying to validate an e-mail address when one is inputted into a form. The email field is not required so blanks can be passed; however, jQuery evaluates the field as not empty even when it is left blank. I'm new to jQuery, so I'm probably overlooking something simple. Offending code is below.

```
var
 emailTest,
 re = /* RegEx here for email addresses */

if ($(formID + ' input[name=email]').val() != '') {  
   emailTest = re.test($(formID + ' input[name=email]').val());  
}
```

`alert($(formID + ' input[name=email]').val() != '');` returns `false` when the email value is left blank, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I know it's not what you are asking for, but why re-invent the wheel? There is already a very good validation plugin for jquery: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: This is legacy code that I'm maintaining. Ripping it out and using the plugin would, in this case, be re-inventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ( ! $(formID + ' input[name=email]').val().length === 0 ) {
    //your code
}
```